# Bootstrap/Angular tab list items are dynamic, set from API response -- causing DOM problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the snippet below in one of my Angular templates.  It's some Bootstrap 3 tabs, but the tab list items (links) are set dynamically after receiving the response from the API.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-right" role="tablist">
  <li ng-repeat="option in options track by $index" ng-class="{'active': $index == 0 }">
    <a href="#{{option.value}}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{option.value}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And then the `tab-content` is also dynamic and references the Angular `$scope` which is set from an API response.

Ex:

```
Resource
  .get()
  .$promise
  .then(function(response) {
    $scope.options = response.options;
  });
```

Doing the above results in the first tab not being shown, but upon clicking other tabs and coming back everything is fine.  However, sometimes there will be only one tab.  And even if there's more, it's not a good UX to see nothing inside of the `tab-content`.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I have a feeling that it might be related to your usage of `track by $index`.  You might need to use a different type of key in your track by that is really unique to each item.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548590/how-do-i-re-initialize-datatables-after-data-has-loaded-via-ajax-in-angularjs/31550937#31550937). Resolve should help to load the data before the controller is executed. If you're not using a router you could also show loading message and display your content after it is resolved. Similiar like in this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/pzk52puj/). If this doesn't help please add more code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you indeed using the angular $resource service or something else ?
Have you tried

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.options = response.options
});
```

If Angular cannot, for some reason, natively watch the response, this might solve your issue.

Comment: Then Angular is already watching the result. Are you using vanilla bootstrap, or an angular implementation e.g. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ ?

Comment: This specific code isn't using Angular UI.  I'd prefer not to if I don't have to because I'd need to redo most of this code using the Angular directive.  So if there's an easy/quick fix for this I'd prefer that.